# Get Images count and positions from Rtf using C#

Tags: c#, parsing, rtf

I have some RTF text. Sometimes text contain some images. Images is displayed inside any rtf editor, but i cannot get images positions programmatically.

I have used RichTextBox control for RTF parsing, but is unable to detect image positions inside text in RichTextBox control
So, does anybody know how to parse RTF and get images positions inside text programmatically using C#?

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx it is open source and able to extract images, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Third-party library (NRtfTree Library) is used in above sample. I would like to find some way without third-party libraries and use only .Net framework functionality.

Comment: Yes, it's a 3rd party library, but open source, so I think you can reuse the needed parts only in your application.